# Sumar valores de colecciones diferentes en MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

Estoy tratando de sumar los valores de cada documento y en cada colección. Me explico mejor, tengo 5 colecciones en MongoDB y en cada colección tengo más de 280.000 documentos. Algo así.

***1ra Colección.***

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5ad99a8a02e5f720785a9b57"),
"fecha" : ISODate("2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
"magnitud1" : {
    "valor" : 46
 },
 "magnitud2" : {
     "valor" : 168
 }
```

***2da Colección.***

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5ad99e4602e5f722f8e665e8"),
"fecha" : ISODate("2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
"magnitud1" : {
    "valor" : 172
},
"magnitud2" : {
    "valor" : 105
},
```

***3ra Colección.***

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5ad9a1b202e5f71c7c1d4374"),
"fecha" : ISODate("2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
"magnitud1" : {
    "valor" : 153
},
"magnitud2" : {
    "valor" : 38
},
```

y así hasta 5 colecciones... donde cada colección tiene más de 280.000 documentos, como ya he comentado.
He probado con esto.

```
db.medidor01.aggregate([
    {$match: {fecha: { $gte: ISODate("2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte: ISODate("2011-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") }} }, 
    {$unwind: "$magnitud1"}, 
    {$group: {
        _id: null, 
        "total": {$sum: "$magnitud1.valor" }
    }}
])
```

Pero esto lo que hace es sumar los valores que se encuentran en la colección *medidor01*.

***Salida:***

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "total" : 3495890
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es lo mismo pero con todas las colecciones de mi base de datos, la cuál tiene la misma estrucutura.

He mirado en [SO.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091826/mongodb-aggregation-on-multiple-collections) y he visto que dicen que no es posible realizar esta operación, aunque no estoy muy seguro que sea la misma pregunta que la mia.

Por lo tanto, mi pregunta inicial es; **¿Es posible realizar esta operación, sumar los valores de todas las colecciones de mi base de datos?**

Comment: La pregunta parece muy similar y dice que no se puede. (solo para sacarte esa duda)